# Increasing AdWords budget improved the bounce rate more than plausable

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, bounce-rate

I increased the budget on Adwords, and immediately Analytics showed a drop on Bounce rate from 50-60% to 1-2%. What can be going wrong? I doubt 98% of visitors are good visitors.

This has been like that for 3 weeks now.

Comment: How long did it take for the drop off in the bounce rate to start? Did you make any other changes besides the budget? Did you change anything in Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using event tracking you may have a passive event which is getting triggered whenever the user enters the page. The solution to this would be to mark the events to `nonInteraction: true`. [Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: From the question, it doesn't sound like events were implemented at the same time as the AdWords budget was changed.